# Tanimoto vector comparison algorithm

Tags: algorithm

What Tanimoto comparison algorithm is exactly doing? How can we use this for comparing with weights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is well-explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)